markdown formatting inside a tooltip using tippy with R (quarto document)
I have a simple .qmd file which knits to an html. It contains some tooltips added with tippy package. Is there a way to use markdown formatting inside a tip?
---
title: 'final'
format: html
fontsize: '18pt'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tippy)
```

Rumpitur <span style='color:blue;'> [invidia]{id='a'} </span> quidam, carissime Iuli...
 
```{r}
tippy::tippy_this(elementId = 'a', 
            tooltip = 'abl. causae', theme = 'light')
```

upd. Right now, my html output looks like this:

What I want to do is, for example, italicise the word "coni." etc.

Could you please clarify what your expected output should look like?

I have added an image and explanation to the original post.
